# Combining different dolls with different dresses

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The math question I got is:

There are $6$ different dolls $\{D_1, \ldots,D_6\}$, $5$ different dresses $\{R_1, \ldots,R_5\}$ and $7$ identical hats. $D_1$ to $D_3$ do not fit $R_5$ and $D_6$ doesn't fit $R_1$ to $R_2$.

The question is how many working combination of dolls and dresses can you make?

Answer: (25 was told it was wrong)

What if the hats where to be used with the (dressed dolls)?
Is it not just $n \times 2$  ($n$ is total combinations) because you have the option of having the hats on or off, and because they are identical, it doesn't matter right?

Comment: May more than one doll wear the same type of dress, or do you mean there are a total of five dresses?

Comment: 5 different dresses and they should work D3 cant fit r5 so you cant combine them

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your answer for the first question is way too small.  Suppose we assign dress $R_5$ to doll $D_6$.  That removes the restrictions on the dresses the other dolls can wear, so the remaining four dresses can be assigned to the remaining dolls in $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 5!$ ways.  There are other cases since $D_6$ could also wear dress $R_3$, $R_4$, or $R_6$.

Comment: ok yeah I messed up now that I have a closer look at the question

Comment: For the hats, there are two choices for each doll.  Either we place a hat on the doll or we do not.  That gives $2^6$ choices (assuming each doll is permitted to wear a single hat).

Comment: so it should be $n$ combination + $2^2$ right ?

Comment: You must multiply the number of ways of distributing the dresses by the number of ways of distributing the hats since the choices are independent.